# Adding active class on for currently loaded account

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have list of accounts coming from `backend`. How would i add active class to my div for the currently loaded account.

```
<% @accounts.each do |account| %>
   <div class="col-md-2">
      <p><%= link_to account.name %></p>
   </div>
<% end %>
```

I have `@active_name` variable which holds Account name on page load. Can i use this variable or should i think of something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, inside your HTML you can do something like:

```
<div class="col-md-2 <%= 'active' if @active_name == account.name %>">
```

Note that if your names are not unique across all accounts, you might have multiple accounts being marked as active.

Comment: Why does it fail when i try to add to my link tag. <p><%= link_to account.name, account_url(account.accountid), class: "<%= 'active' if @active_account_name == account.name %>" %></p>

Comment: because you cant nest ERB tags inside ERB tags.

Comment: is there any way we can add active class to link_to tag the way we are doing with div container.

Comment: sure, just use a simple conditional - something like `class: ('active' if @active_name == account.name)`